# Cannot convert from object to int

Tags: c#, android, json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I got this working before but it looks like something has changed in Xamarin or the Android SDK. I am trying to populate a spinner with deserialized json data. However the spinner adapter wont accept my list anymore? It says I cannot convert from object to int? Tutorial I followed before [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hICUZU7CKsA)

```
    Spinner spinner;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        string urlmountains = "http://my.azurewebsites.net/api/Mountains";

        JsonValue json1 = FetchMountains(urlmountains);

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json1.ToString());

        spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
        //this line ------------------------------------------------->
        spinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, list); // Error here cannot convert from Object to Int?

    }


    private JsonValue FetchMountains(string urlmountains)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlmountains));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc1 = JsonObject.Load(stream);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc1.ToString());

                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc1;
            }
        }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public double? Latitude { get; set; }

        public double? Longitude { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double? Height_m { get; set; }

        public double? Height_ft { get; set; }

        public double? temperature { get; set; }

        public double? humidity { get; set; }

        public double? snowCover { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your list is of `RootObject`, but your `ArrayAdapter` is of `string`, so it looks like your IDE is trying to apply the `ArrayAdapter` constructor that takes `(Context, int, int)`. Change your `ArrayAdapter`'s type argument to `RootObject`. That is, `... = new ArrayAdapter<RootObject>...`.

Comment: I thought this [looked familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647827/retrieve-one-item-from-a-list-and-display-it-in-a-spinner). As I recall, you had a comment there that indicated that the issue was resolved. What happened?

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked. Lost my work a while back so had to use the code I had on that question that I posted a while back (that you also answered) but just couldnt figure out how to solve it this time round. Apologies on the double post!

Comment: Cool. Remember to add an appropriate `ToString()` override to your `RootObject` class, so `ArrayAdapter` displays the right thing.

Comment: Yeah I did that, I followed the link you sent me in the last question. All 30 objects are displaying now from my web api. Although I am sure I had the names instead of just "object"...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Whadya mean?

Comment: `var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json1.ToString());` You had linked me a question that says to do this. Is this the override you mean? When I did this a while back I was sure I somehow got the names of the mountains rather than just object. However I cant remember how I did it?

Comment: Yeah, you've got that in your current code. I'm talking about overriding the `ToString()` method in the `RootObject` class to return `Name`, presumably. E.g., `public override string ToString() { return Name; }`

Comment: Thats that done. Thanks Mike.

Comment: No problem. I'll put an answer together here in a minute, so you can have something better to refer back to next time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list` is a `List` of `RootObject`:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(...);
```

But your `ArrayAdapter` wants a `List` of `string`:

```
spinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(...);
```

Your IDE can't resolve an appropriate constructor, since those types don't match. Change your `ArrayAdapter`'s type argument to `RootObject`:

```
spinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RootObject>(...);
```

Additionally, `ArrayAdapter` displays the value returned by its model class's `ToString()` method, so you need to override that in the `RootObject` class to return the desired `string`.

```
public class RootObject
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike would you be able to help on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685951/how-to-plot-polygon-data-from-csv-file-kml-fusion-table-workaround-for-android

Comment: Ooh, probably not. I've not done anything with Maps, so I wouldn't even begin to know what all the possibilities are for that csv format - particularly the geometry - nor the appropriate Maps classes. I mean, I could write code to parse that particular example to `LatLng`s, but another problem would be that it would be in Java, since I don't really know Xamarin/C# and have no way to test it, so it wouldn't be much better than your pseudocode there. Sorry.

Comment: No problem Mike, thanks for being approachable! Much appreciated for taking the time to look.